# How to write a HtmlHelper extension method that renders a partial view?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to create an `HtmlHelper`extension to render an Autocomplete. Something like this:

```
@Html.AutoCompleteFor(x => x.CustomerId);
```

The problem is that the `Html.RenderPartial(...)` returns void, so my `AutoCompleteFor` method must also be void. But Razor won't let it compile because @Html.X will only compile if X returns an Object.

I know I can bypass this problem by calling this, instead:

```
@{ Html.AutoCompleteFor(x => x.CustomerId); }
```

But that will make my code to look inconsistent with the `@Html.EditorFor`

I need to return a PartialView from inside my an HtmlHelper

Some considerations:

- I know you might think that this would be, somehow, breaking the MVC pattern, but MVC itself does that. The `Html.EditorFor` will try to find a view and return it.
- I'm  only trying to do that because I need `foreign-key` property to use `jQuery-AutoComplete` by default. I wasn't able to tell MVC to use my template for foreign-key properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `Html.Partial`, which returns a `HelperResult` object rather than writing directly to the page.
You can then return the `HelperResult` to the caller.

Technically, you could also just `return null`, but that would be a really dumb idea.

Comment: That works! I got confused with Html.RenderPartial(...) Thanks!